# Unable to test in microsoft chat bot registration

Tags: botframework

[image]

When I test my chat bot on the bot registration page I am getting a "MethodNotAllowed" error

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>    method (HTTP verb) is being used.

The bot is published as azure app service, and was working fine in the emulator using the bots appid and password.

Comment: _"was working fine in the emulator"_ So is it still working OK from the emulator? I had a (different) problem with the connection test when I had changed the behaviour of the `ProcessSystemMessage` nethod in the bot controller, as the connection test uses a "Ping" message. Try one of those from the emulator and see if it works.

Comment: Check your endpoint to ensure it is https (not http).

Answer (score 2):

As it's stated in Bot Framework [documention](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication)

> Your bot communicates to the Bot Connector Service using **HTTP over a
>   secured channel** (SSL/TLS)

So please make sure you are using HTTPS instead of HTTP, and if url is properly set in dev portal.